# Magento - Get Payment Method used in order in totals.phtml

Tags: php, magento

i'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i want to get the used order payment method in the totals.phtml

Here is what i have in: totals.phtml:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
        <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
        <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

I want to get a simple echo with the the payment method like `<?PHP echo $PaymentMethod; ?>`

How can i get the payment method used for the order ?

Comment: Why are you toggling PHP on and off every line? It makes your code very hard to read (and, I imagine, hard to write).

Comment: @Chris it's just Magento's templates, they are as ugly as that, all the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethod(); ?>
```

It will return the code of the used payment method.

Comment: I got this error when i try to do that `Fatal error: Call to a member function getPayment() on a non-object in /public_html/beta/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml on line`

Comment: Are you trying to show this block on order view page? Or on any other page?

Comment: I've fixed the problem. You answer is correct! Thank you!